# Nginx won't let med add any other sites

Tags: nginx, centos8

I've tried creating two config files for my two sites in /usr/share/nginx/modules, but I get one of two errors no matter what:

```
http directive is duplicate
```

Ok lets remove it from config file....

```
server directive is not allowed here
```

Why is it doing this and how do I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had included /etc/nginx/sites-enabled too early in my nginx.conf file.

Moving it to the bottom of the http {} block seems to have resolved it.

**EDIT:** I'm not exactly sure that was the only thing causing issues.